# Connecting Azure Mobile Services to UWP

Tags: c#, azure, win-universal-app, azure-mobile-services

I have created a Mobile service in Azure, and connected an SQL database in it.
I installed the required Nuget Package *Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client*, and i tried *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices* , and inserted this code in my App.xaml.cs:

`public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("https://sqlbackend.azurewebsites.net");`

**The Problem is:** When i come to connect an azure mobile service to the project, they say it is not supported.

Is there any way to connect my project to an azure mobile service?

[image: Connected Services panel]

Answer (score 2):

What kind of project the client is?

If it's **Azure Mobile Service** or **Azure Mobile App** itself, no need to add a connected service, just right-click the project,select **Publish**,import the web app publish settings file and publish to Azure.

If it's **Windows Phone WebView App** or others supported by tooling gesture, the configure button will be enabled and the code in `App.xaml.cs` should be:

`public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient`
`("https://sqlbackend.azurewebsites.net", "XXXX-APPLICATION-KEY-XXXXX");`

The second parameter is application key which is generated here:

[image]

**PS:** The code above and adding connected service(Azure Mobile Service) reach the same result and no need to use both at the same time.

Comment: Yep I got it after following a tutorial and some guides. I am waiting for the first guy to edit his answer so i choose his answer, but thank you for your straight answer as well :)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old Azure Mobile Services client.

Links for you:

- HOWTO:
  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/
- SDK Docs:
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt419521(v=azure.10).aspx

When you convert to using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices, it will inject the right header and you will not get the Unsupported message.

After reviewing your question again, you need to match up the type in the server with the type in the client. If you have created an Azure Mobile Service, then your client should be Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client. If you have created an Azure App Service Mobile App, then your client should be Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Client - the links I provided were for Azure Mobile Apps (not Services in the client). I recommend Azure Mobile Apps (which can be considered the latest generation of such). Tutorials are available on azure.com

Comment: I tried the namespace you told me about, still the same. Btw the one I am using is a newer version than the one you suggested. If any extra explanation is available I am more than happy to listen. :)

Comment: The HOWTO docs I linked spell out what you need to do.  The SDK docs I pointed to are the latest available and were published less than a week ago.  There is no newer version available than that.

Comment: After reviewing your question again, you need to match up the type in the server with the type in the client.  If you have created an Azure Mobile Service, then your client should be Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.  If you have created an Azure App Service Mobile App, then your client should be Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Client - the links I provided were for Azure Mobile Apps (not Services in the client).  I recommend Azure Mobile Apps (which can be considered the latest generation of such).  Tutorials are available on azure.com

Comment: I am sorry for the disturbance, I just mixed different tutorials,as usual and got lost in between. I just needed to download the SDK and publish it to azure and now working on the service. Thank you for your support :)    P.S: edit your answer so i choose it, add the big comment you wrote to your answer.